# Need suggestion or help to modify a macro that can search a sub-string and format after wildcard search for VBA

Tags: vba, format, substring

I have a question for you all brilliant people here, who are experts in VBA.
I have found this super cool macro that colors a text that is provided through an input box.
However, I tried to make a little modification, I am trying to make it to use a wildcard `"*"`
for instance if I provide `VBA*`, in the input the string from `"VBA"` to end of the text in that selected range should be formatted.
A goggled sub-string formatting vba code. None were found so I altered this code hoping one of you can add some magic in a moment.

This is the code I found in search:

```vb
Sub X_FormatSubStrings()
    Dim xHStr As String, xStrTmp As String
    Dim xHStrLen As Long, xCount As Long, i As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xArr
    On Error Resume Next
    xHStr = Application.InputBox("What is the string to highlight:", "Enter the string", "")
    If TypeName(xHStr) < > "String" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xHStrLen = Len(xHStr)
    For Each xCell In Selection
        xArr = Split(xCell.Value, xHStr)
        xCount = UBound(xArr)
        If xCount > 0 Then
            xStrTmp = ""
            For i = 0 To xCount - 1
                xStrTmp = xStrTmp & xArr(i)
                xCell.Characters(Len(xStrTmp) + 1, xHStrLen).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                xCell.Characters(Len(xStrTmp) + 1, xHStrLen).Font.Bold = 3
                xStrTmp = xStrTmp & xHStr
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Which application does this apply to? Excel? Bad idea to have `On Error Resume Next` - turning off error handling will suppress important information about why code may not be working. Comment it out, run the code, then use the [edit] link to include the missing information in your question.

Comment: Karthik, perhaps you should carefully review the code to understand what it does, and then you may either answer your own question or find a more specific question. I can see a number of issues in the code that are outside the bounds of your question to address (e.g. `On Error`, not using the `InputBox` parameters to force a `String`, strange use of Hungarian Notation, `Selection`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though question is not clear and the code have multiple issues, I presumed that it applies to Excel and will intended to work only with * as wildcard charterer. Code is  tried to be modified for presumed intended use.

```
Sub X_FormatSubStrings()
Dim xHStr As String, CellStr As String
Dim xStrTmp As String, xHStrLen As Long
Dim xCount As Long, i As Long, StPos As Long, EndPos As Long, Pos As Long
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xArr

xHStr = InputBox("What is the string to highlight:", "Enter the string", "*asd*rt*ss*")
If TypeName(xHStr) <> "String" Then Exit Sub
If Len(xHStr) = 0 Then Exit Sub
xArr = Split(xHStr, "*")

    For Each xCell In Selection
    CellStr = xCell.Value
    StPos = 0
    EndPos = 0


            For i = LBound(xArr) To UBound(xArr)
            Pos = InStr(1, CellStr, xArr(i))
            If Pos <= 0 Then Exit For
            If i = LBound(xArr) Then StPos = Pos
            If i = UBound(xArr) Then EndPos = Pos + Len(xArr(i)) - 1
            If i = UBound(xArr) And xArr(i) = "" Then EndPos = Len(CellStr)
            Next i

            If StPos > 0 And EndPos >= StPos Then
            xCell.Characters(StPos, EndPos - StPos + 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            xCell.Characters(StPos, EndPos - StPos + 1).Font.Bold = True
            End If

    Next xCell
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed AU thank you for the solution, you made my day easier.. its very helpful as guys like you guide the people in need of knowledge, great work keep up